# Accessing EKS using kubectl from an EC2 instance using a IAM role

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to configure kubectl in an EC2 instance that has an IAM role attached and no credentials attached to AWS cli. I have edited the config map for kubectl and added the below rule to include the assumed role.

```
- rolearn: arn:aws:sts::<account-id>:assumed-role/EC2WorkstationRole/<ec2-instanceid>
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:masters
    


I get the below error on running kubectl get pods:

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: 
arn:aws:sts::<account-id>:assumed-role/EC2WorkstationRole/<ec2-instanceid> is not 
authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: 
arn:aws:sts::<account-id>:assumed-role/EC2WorkstationRole/<ec2-instanceid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to fix the aws-auth configmap so it allow the IAM Role to be essentially an admin, it should be as follows:

```
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::${accountid}:role/EC2WorkstationRole
  username: EC2WorkstationRole
  groups:
    - system:masters
```

Also, make sure that the trust policy attached to your IAM Role has sts:AssumeRole permissions.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have this rule as well. Doesn't work. I must be missing something

Comment: Did you fetch your kubeconfig using aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name cluster-name?

Comment: Yes i did that using --role-arn and provided my role arn as well

Comment: Did you run update-kubeconfig from the ec2 instance in question?

Comment: @binjiezhao Yes i ran that from the ec2 instance